# DS18B20 and Pi Pico returns strange ROM

Tags: pi-pico

I have one DS18B20 connected on a breadboard to a pi pico with a 4.7K pull-up.
Using the example code:

```
import machine, onewire, ds18x20, time

ds_pin = machine.Pin(4)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))

roms = ds_sensor.scan()
print('Found DS devices: ', roms)

while True:
  ds_sensor.convert_temp()
  time.sleep_ms(750)
  for rom in roms:
    print(rom)
    tempC = ds_sensor.read_temp(rom)
    tempF = tempC * (9/5) +32
    print('temperature (ºC):', "{:.2f}".format(tempC))
    print('temperature (ºF):', "{:.2f}".format(tempF))
    print()
  time.sleep(5)
```

It works and returns the correct temperature but the ROM found by the scan doesn't make sense to me.

```
Found DS devices:  [bytearray(b'(\xf6i\x9b\x00\x00\x00I')]
```

I expected 64 bits formatted in some standard manner?
Reducing the pull-up to 2.35K makes no difference.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is simply 0x28f6699b00000049

Answer (score 0):

There's a few confusing things here that are byproducts of the perhaps somewhat wacky way python formats bytearrays.<sup>1</sup> At first glance they look essentially like hex strings:

```
bytearray(b'(\xf6i\x9b\x00\x00\x00I')
            ^    ^                ^
```

But in fact they are a mixture of hex notation and ASCII characters, the latter taking precedence when a value is in the printable range: decimal 32 / hex 20 / ascii ' ' (space) to decimal 126 / hex 7e / ascii '~', or escape printable values (eg. '\n' = 10 = \x0a).

Notice those parentheses aren't balanced because the second `(` is actually the first byte of the array (also notice it is inside the quotes),
an ascii character with value decimal 40 / hex 28.  The other two ascii bytes are `i` and `I`, plus the five hex bytes = 64 bits.

From a linux console you can get a chart of ASCII values via `ascii`, though by default it doesn't show the escapable characters as such (but `man ascii` is sort of interesting).  There are also such charts online.

---

1. It's not unprecedented, there are various tools for manipulating "binary" data (where every byte has the full 8-bit 0-255 potential) that print things this way.  This makes it easy to spot clumps of embedded intelligible text.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are planning to do with the value read.

As goldilicks explained this a an ASCII representation (designed for communication links) which are (almost) unreadable by a human.
I always convert if I need to examine them.

It is simple to convert (the following prints as hex).

```
BA=bytearray(b'(\xf6i\x9b\x00\x00\x00I')
print(bytes(BA).hex())
```

You can also access each element of the array.

```
print(BA[0])
40
```